# Draw specific letters and numbers in python

Tags: python, random

I made a function to generate a combination of letters and random numbers in python:

```
from random import choice, random, sample

def generateKeyId(self):
    keyId = sample(ascii_uppercase,4)+sample(digits,4)+sample(ascii_uppercase,1)
    return ''.join(keyId)
```

this is one of the exits for example:

```
DCAT5087H
```

But what I really want is to generate an output with a combination of 1-200 and A-J
Example:

```
6A

32F

60H
```

in that order, number and string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
from random import randint, choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

letters = ascii_uppercase[:10]  # A-J


def generateKeyId():
    return str(randint(1, 200)) + choice(letters)

>>> generateKeyId()
'33D'
>>> generateKeyId()
'115D'
>>> generateKeyId()
'62B'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from random import randint

def generateKeyId():
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]
    keyId =  str(randint(0,200)) + letters[randint(0,9)]
    return keyId
```